# List music files

Tags: android

I just started on a new project and i would need some help.
I need to have a list. In the list, all songs on the sd card should be shown.

I don't know that much about android so far, but should i use a simplelistview to view the songs and an adaptor to get the songs?

Answer (score 0):

See the example below:

http://z4android.blogspot.com/2011/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html

Comment: managedQuery is deprecated and shall not be used anymore. It might throw random exceptions!